# Largest webmail web app written on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rainloop is an incredible webmail application written in PHP.

Does a rails version exist? The only one I can find is this:
https://github.com/lmanolov/mailr

Whose last commit was over two years ago :/

Not opinion based, not looking for opinions, just want to know of there is a large, open source, active webmail app written on Rails.

Comment: [Mailr](http://mailr.org/) but it is dead for years now.